# How to decrease sensitivity of automatic axis adjustment in Highcharts when dragging points

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts

In Highcharts with drag and drop, the axis automatically adjusts so that you can drag outside of the current range. For example, in the following chart, the Y-axis starts out at 2-9:

```js
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Highcharts from "highcharts";
import more from "highcharts/highcharts-more";
import draggable from "highcharts/modules/draggable-points";
import HighchartsReact from "highcharts-react-official";

if (typeof Highcharts === "object") {
  more(Highcharts);
  draggable(Highcharts);
}

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <HighchartsReact
        highcharts={Highcharts}
        constructorType={"chart"}
        options={{
          tooltip: {
            valueDecimals: 2
          },
          series: [
            {
              name: "Range",
              data: [[0, 3, 8], [1, 3, 8], [2, 3, 8]],
              type: "arearange",
              dragDrop: {
                draggableHigh: true,
                draggableLow: true
              },
              linkedTo: ":previous"
            }
          ]
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

For a live example, see [this demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/too-sensitive-y-axis-adjustment-with-highcharts-drag-and-drop-h7srf).

The problem is that the adjustment is far too quick. For example, try to drag a point from `y = 8` to `y = 14`. The Y-axis adjustment is so sensitive that the point is at 30 before I have time to stop dragging. And when I drag the point back down, the same problem occurs in the opposite direction. Having tried a few times, I'm completely unable to set the point to a value of 14.

So the question is: How can I reduce the speed of the automatic adjustment?

(Note that there is a [`dragSensitivity`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.arearange.dragDrop.dragSensitivity) option, but it's not relevant in this case.)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to set the **liveRedraw** feature to false? I think that this will fill your requirements because when this option is set to false the dragging precision is much better.

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/too-sensitive-y-axis-adjustment-with-highcharts-drag-and-drop-7f41g

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.arearange.dragDrop.liveRedraw

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about that one. Unfortunately, it makes the drag and drop interface less intuitive, so we're not sure if it's an improvement overall.

Comment: Reported in issue tracker: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/12903